# How to write a query that builds a string dynamically based on a 2 tables

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join

I have 2 tables: `MainTable` and `ControlTable`.

I want to write a query that builds a string representing a file path.
File path will be built dynamically depending on a query result between two tables.

Main table has the following columns:
`ControlNumber`
`CustomerID`
`CustomerStatement`

The Control table has only one column: `ControlNumber`

I need to write a query that checks if Main table has a `ControlNumber` defined in Control Table.
If there is a match, I append `\FolderA` to my `FilePath`
If no match, I append `\FolderB`

Ending result will be something like this:

`C:\Customers\FolderA` or `C:\Customers\FolderB`

I suspect I need to use `left join`

How can I do that?

Comment: Where does the `FilePath` come from?

Comment: What database and version of it are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that you want a left join. Combine that with a `case...when` expression to determine the value:

```
select 
  *, 
  case 
    when Control.ControlNumber is not null 
    then '\FolderA' 
    else '\FolderB' 
  end as FilePath
from main 
left join control on main.ControlNumber = control.ControlNumber
```

It's not clear where the rest of the path comes from; maybe it's static and you want to concatenate it with the value from the case expression:

```
'c:\customers' + -- or concat() or || depending on sql dialect
case when Control.ControlNumber is not null then '\FolderA' else '\FolderB' end as FilePath
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'C:\' || CustomerID || '\FolderA'
FROM MainTable 
WHERE EXISTS
( SELECT 1 FROM ControlNumber WHERE ControlTable.ControlNumber = MainTable.CustomerID  )
UNION
SELECT 'C:\' || CustomerID || '\FolderB'
FROM MainTable 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( SELECT 1 FROM ControlTable WHERE ControlTable.ControlNumber = MainTable.ControlNumber)
```